# how to solve this Nameerror in python

Tags: python

I am not good at the conversion between str and int。

```
import linecache
n=linecache.getline('input-a4-problem_1-sample.txt',1)
number_of_stock=eval(n)
fp = open('input-a4-problem_1-sample.txt','r')
stock_value=fp.readlines()[1:]
stock_value=fp.readlines()[1:]
fp.close()
while(len(stock_value)<number_of_stock):
    x_high = stock_value[0]
    x_low = stock_value[0]
    max_loss = 0
    for x in stock_value:
        if x > x_high:
            x_high = x
            x_low = x
        elif x < x_low:
            x_low = x
            loss = x_low - x_high
        if loss < max_loss:
            max_loss = loss
print(max_loss)
```

[image]

Comment: Please fix the formatting and show the actual stack trace.

Comment: I can't understand what the code is intended to do.

Comment: You can't use `loss`, defined in the `elif` statement, in the following `if` condition.

Answer (score 2):

Your error isn't about converting types

`if x > x_high`, then you never assign a value to `loss`, but then you're checking `if loss < max_loss`, and `loss` does not exist

You should assign it some default value before the for loop like you did for max loss

Also, you have an infinite while loop because `len(stock_value) < number_of_stocks` is always true. The length nor number of stocks change in value

Comment: the types of x_high and x_low are 'str',I can't subtract between them.what should I do to solve this problem.

Comment: `int(stock_value[0])`